# Apache2 does not find python3.8 based virtual env and load python3.6 based env

Tags: django, ubuntu-18.04, mod-wsgi, apache2.4

i have an issue with a django based application deployment with apache2 on ubuntu18.04 with python3.8.

**Internal Server Error**

*The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.*

I installed the mod_wsgi and apache2 as:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

I setup venv folder in the project folder.

I get error logs as:

## Error Log 1

```
[Tue Jun 21 08:34:13.966782 2022] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 660:tid 140673610189760] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jun 21 20:11:41.285936 2022] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 32599:tid 139678582156224] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jun 21 20:11:41.287426 2022] [core:notice] [pid 32599:tid 139678582156224] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

## Error Log 2

```
[Tue Jun 21 20:11:44.374973 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 32600:tid 139678384367360] [remote 78.180.30.203:4742] mod_wsgi (pid=32600): Target WSGI script '/home/tealy/warehouse/warehouse/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Jun 21 20:11:44.375046 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 32600:tid 139678384367360] [remote 78.180.30.203:4742] mod_wsgi (pid=32600): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/tealy/warehouse/warehouse/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Jun 21 20:11:44.375175 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 32600:tid 139678384367360] [remote 78.180.30.203:4742] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Jun 21 20:11:44.375230 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 32600:tid 139678384367360] [remote 78.180.30.203:4742]   File "/home/tealy/warehouse/warehouse/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Tue Jun 21 20:11:44.375244 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 32600:tid 139678384367360] [remote 78.180.30.203:4742]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Tue Jun 21 20:11:44.375272 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 32600:tid 139678384367360] [remote 78.180.30.203:4742] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

My .conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        Alias /static /home/tealy/warehouse/static
        <Directory /home/tealy/warehouse/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/tealy/warehouse/warehouse>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/tealy/warehouse/warehouse/wsgi.py
        WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/tealy/warehouse/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages python-home=/home/tealy/warehouse/venv
        #WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/tealy/warehouse python-home=/home/tealy/warehouse/venv
        WSGIProcessGroup django_app


</VirtualHost>
```

Error log ModuleNotFoundError:

```
[Thu Jun 23 07:31:45.354231 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 27238:tid 140362885576448] [remote 78.180.30.203:2826] mod_wsgi (pid=27238): Target WSGI script '/home/tealy/warehouse/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Jun 23 07:31:45.377898 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 27238:tid 140362919147264] [remote 78.180.30.203:4052] mod_wsgi (pid=27238): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/tealy/warehouse/warehouse/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Jun 23 07:31:45.378128 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 27238:tid 140362919147264] [remote 78.180.30.203:4052] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jun 23 07:31:45.378204 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 27238:tid 140362919147264] [remote 78.180.30.203:4052]   File "/home/tealy/warehouse/warehouse/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Thu Jun 23 07:31:45.378217 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 27238:tid 140362919147264] [remote 78.180.30.203:4052]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Thu Jun 23 07:31:45.378235 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 27238:tid 140362919147264] [remote 78.180.30.203:4052]   File "/home/tealy/warehouse/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Thu Jun 23 07:31:45.378245 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 27238:tid 140362919147264] [remote 78.180.30.203:4052]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Thu Jun 23 07:31:45.378260 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 27238:tid 140362919147264] [remote 78.180.30.203:4052]   File "/home/tealy/warehouse/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
[Thu Jun 23 07:31:45.378270 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 27238:tid 140362919147264] [remote 78.180.30.203:4052]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Thu Jun 23 07:31:45.378285 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 27238:tid 140362919147264] [remote 78.180.30.203:4052]   File "/home/tealy/warehouse/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
[Thu Jun 23 07:31:45.378304 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 27238:tid 140362919147264] [remote 78.180.30.203:4052]     self._setup(name)
[Thu Jun 23 07:31:45.378321 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 27238:tid 140362919147264] [remote 78.180.30.203:4052]   File "/home/tealy/warehouse/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
[Thu Jun 23 07:31:45.378331 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 27238:tid 140362919147264] [remote 78.180.30.203:4052]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Thu Jun 23 07:31:45.378346 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 27238:tid 140362919147264] [remote 78.180.30.203:4052]   File "/home/tealy/warehouse/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
[Thu Jun 23 07:31:45.378356 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 27238:tid 140362919147264] [remote 78.180.30.203:4052]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Thu Jun 23 07:31:45.378370 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 27238:tid 140362919147264] [remote 78.180.30.203:4052]   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[Thu Jun 23 07:31:45.378380 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 27238:tid 140362919147264] [remote 78.180.30.203:4052]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Thu Jun 23 07:31:45.378395 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 27238:tid 140362919147264] [remote 78.180.30.203:4052]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
[Thu Jun 23 07:31:45.378411 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 27238:tid 140362919147264] [remote 78.180.30.203:4052]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
[Thu Jun 23 07:31:45.378428 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 27238:tid 140362919147264] [remote 78.180.30.203:4052]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Thu Jun 23 07:31:45.378444 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 27238:tid 140362919147264] [remote 78.180.30.203:4052]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Thu Jun 23 07:31:45.378460 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 27238:tid 140362919147264] [remote 78.180.30.203:4052]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
[Thu Jun 23 07:31:45.378476 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 27238:tid 140362919147264] [remote 78.180.30.203:4052]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
[Thu Jun 23 07:31:45.378493 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 27238:tid 140362919147264] [remote 78.180.30.203:4052]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Thu Jun 23 07:31:45.378522 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 27238:tid 140362919147264] [remote 78.180.30.203:4052] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'warehouse'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to let apache2 use the right python version, you need to set the configuration of apache2 properly. If you use WSGI, you can do it by setting the WSGIDaemonProcess in your apache's config. There are two other parameters: **python-path** and **python-home**. Set the python-path to your python's site-packages (inside your venv) and your python-home to your venv's root. For e.g. in my case (/etc/apache2/site-available/000-default.conf):

```
    WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-path=/var/project/myapp/.venv/lib/python
3.8/site-packages python-home=/var/project/myapp/.venv
```

This has solved my problem.

UPDATED2 (continued)
It's now about the permissions of folders and files. Please make sure **not to put the project under root user**. It depends how you start your apache2, in my case I'm using www-data user and I have my venv under the project folder (as you see above). What I need to do:

```
# Change ownership and group recursively to www-data
$ sudo chown www-data:www-data -R <project-top dir>
# Make sure that they have the permissions (in my case: add group permission is enough)
$ sudo chmod g+rwx -R <project-top dir>
# restart apache2
```

Comment: The issue is apache2 does not utilize the python3. 8. I am already using python3. 8 and it works. Somehow it choses python3. 6.

Comment: Please see my update above. If you still have the problem, please post your apache2 config as well

Comment: Hi, it now tries to utilize python3.8 but it can not find the project module. This is where it tries to employ python3.6 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module

Comment: please see my updates above

Comment: You might also want to uninstall python3.6 if you don't use it. Since you have already python3.8. f you don't set any hardcore reference to 3.6, this will force apache2 to use python3.8: $sudo apt-get remove --purge python3.6

Comment: Removing python3.6 crushes the Server since Ubuntu 18.04 depends on it.

Comment: Hi, I tried to chown and chmod but still the issue remains.

Comment: You need to post the latest error logs and config(if you modified it). Do you really have the 'place holders' in logs and config? or did you replace them manually? if yes, please replace them with name only, otherwise it makes more complicated to analyse the errors

Comment: I updated .conf file and placeholders. The issue remains.

Comment: the python-path referenced by the config (/home/cevik/depodenetim/venv/lib/python3.8..) is not the same as the error log displayed: /home/tealy/warehouse/venv/lib/python3.8/.. This means, the apache2 reads different config file (not the one that you posted)

Comment: I am sorry i had edited it. Now you can see the right one.

Comment: Can you install warehouse in your venv ( you need to activate this first):  $pip install warehouse. See if the errors is gone

Comment: warehouse is not a python module it is my django project name hence it can not install the warehouse.

Comment: Are you able to run the project without apache2 using the same venv ? ($python manage.py runserver) or do you get the same error massage? I find the last errors generated not really related to your first issue. You might want to accept this answer and create a new issue for a new problem